git branch from commit in GH workflow: refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow
I am trying to create a git branch from a specific commit SHA within a Github workflow.
It looks like this:
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - main
      - release/*

...
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}
          fetch-depth: 0

...
- name: Create the release branch
        shell: pwsh
        env:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }} 
          commit_sha: ${{ github.event.inputs.commit_sha }}
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}      
        run: |
          .\scripts\MyPowershellScript.ps1


Within the powershell script I am doing:
$releaseBranch = ... # 

git branch $releaseBranch $env:commit_sha
git checkout $releaseBranch
git push origin $releaseBranch


The git push fails with the following error:
! [remote rejected] release/v0.7 -> release/v0.7 (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/Create_Release.yaml` without `workflows` permission)

If I remove $env:commit_sha arg from the git branch command everything works fine.
I don't understand what's the problem of branching from a commit and why it says that I am trying to update the workflow.
I would appreciate if someone could explain me why this is happening.

The error:
refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/Create_Release.yaml`

is happening because your powershell is trying to perform a checkout of the new branch. This would obviously clean your working folder.
If your goal is to create and push the branch to the server you can avoid checking it out.
Do:
git push origin $($env:commit_sha):refs/heads/$releaseBranch

